# Please help me identify this caterpillar species (Sabah, Malaysia)

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

[image]

I kinda having trouble searching the internet to find this caterpillar name. Does anybody know what kind of species they are?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Cool looking caterpillars. To increase the chances of getting a correct id, identification questions should also include: 1) habitat information — for example what plant are they on; and 2) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: If you can get a photo of just one of these from the side it may help even more; from what I can see these "caterpillars" are destined to become some sort of sawfly rather than a butterfly or moth (I _think_ I see more than five pairs of prolegs on at least one of these--a butterfly or moth will have no more than five pairs of prolegs).